# table is vanished when there is no data from the database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a table that is showing the data from the database.the code is listed below:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="width:300px" id="contact">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:180px" data-bind="text:title1"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the i am using ajax to fetch the data:

```
$(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M dd,yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
                $('#date').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, date, inst.settings));
                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                var day = date.getDate();
                var year = date.getFullYear();
                var date1 = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
                $.post(root+"home/index?json",{date:date1}, function(data) {ko.applyBindings(new DynamicModel(data.calendar1),document.getElementById("contact"));});
        },
    });
});
```

Table is showing the data that is coming from the database but is getting vanished when there is no data from the database 
so please help me for this..

Comment: You haven't made a question, have you?

Comment: yes..i want to show the table as it is even if there is no data from the database..that not occurring in my case.its getting vanished,neither showing the data nor the table even.

Comment: no not working after adding thead also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a thead will help as then it will at least show the header. Since the empty table will not generate any code I am guessing it is not showing up

Comment: i have added thead also but i am getting  the same result here my code is <thead> 
                  <tr>
                  <td id="date"></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                <tbody data-bind="foreach:items">
                <tr>
                        <td style="height:180px" data-bind="text:title1"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </thead>